# Detect if program is running with full administrator rights

Tags: c++, winapi, uac, detect, administrator

I need to determine if my program is running with full administrator rights. By that I mean if uac is turned on (for win vista/7) that I need to determine if the program actually has admin rights (like if the user right clicked and selected "run as administator") and not limited by uac. How do I do this in C++?

Comment: Don't put [tags] in the subject line. That is what the Tags are for.

Comment: You can just try doing the operation you need the rights for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a process has elevated privileges in windows 7 using native C++ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196552/how-to-check-if-a-process-has-elevated-privileges-in-windows-7-using-native-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a process has the administrative rights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046097/how-to-check-if-a-process-has-the-administrative-rights)

Answer (score 12):

- Win9x: Everyone is "admin"
- NT4: [OpenThreadToken/OpenProcessToken + GetTokenInformation(...,TokenGroups,...) on DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS SID in a loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379554(VS.85).aspx)
- 2000+: OpenThreadToken/OpenProcessToken + [CheckTokenMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389(v=VS.85).aspx) on DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS SID

Other alternatives are: [IsUserAnAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463(VS.85).aspx) or [AccessCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-accesscheck)

Checking the TOKEN_ELEVATION* stuff in the token is not required for testing the current process but it is useful if you need to find out if the user could elevate because they have a split token etc.

Answer (score 1):

An expansion on Anders' answer for those (like me) who are less Windows literate:

```
    BOOL isMember;
    PSID administratorsGroup = NULL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT =
        SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &administratorsGroup))
    {
        throw(oops_t(GetLastError(), "AllocateAndInitializeSid"));
    }

    if (!CheckTokenMembership(nullptr, administratorsGroup, &isMember))
    {
        throw(oops_t(GetLastError(), "CheckTokenMembership"));
    }

    if (!isMember)
    {
        throw(oops_t(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, "Test for Admin privileges"));
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to add  FreeSid(administratorsGroup);.