# Get the logon session of a user in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sessionid, pid

I want to get a handle on the current logon session of processes whose parent is explorer.exe.

If we run a process as administrator or a service it won't have a logon session. The reason I want to get the logon session is that I have a program (.exe) which I want to restrict opening when a user tries to open it via (right click on the .exe--> run as administrator) and when a user opens it via administrator we don't have a logon session associated with it whereas when a user opens it by double clicking on it, it has a logon session associated with it.

I searched quite some places, but I just get the process for getting the logon SID. If someone wants more information, you can download http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 and under the explorer --> right click on any program executing --> security. Here you will find the logon session.

Comment: Every process is associated with a logon session. Are you sure you are running Process Explorer elevated ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question ? This is the question I read "How can I make my process run elevated all the time (always run as administrator)". Is that it ?

Comment: @ixe013: No thats not what I have written. I do not understand why youre seeing that. let me see what it looks like after logging out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the logon session associated with a process by using [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) followed by [`GetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `TokenStatistics` option.  However, this is not a sensible way of finding out whether or not a process was launched using "run as administrator" because there is no straightforward way to determine whether a particular logon session is elevated or not.  It is not true that a process launched with "run as administrator" will not have a logon session.

To find out whether a process was "run as administrator" use the `TokenElevationType` option.  This should return `TokenElevationTypeFull` if and only if "run as administrator" was used.

(One caveat: I'm not certain what `TokenElevationType` will return if a non-administrative user uses "run as administrator" and then enters an administrator username and password.  You should test this scenario.  You might want to use `TokenElevation` rather than `TokenElevationType`.)

If what you really want to know is whether the process has administrative privilege, you should use [`CheckTokenMembership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  Look for the Administrators group.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has sample code that does exactly this.

The distinction here is what you want to happen if UAC is disabled (and the user is an administrator) or if the user is the local Administrator.  In these cases there is no "run as administrator" option, all processes are run with administrator privilege automatically.  If you want to detect these cases, use `CheckTokenMembership`.  If you only want to detect the cases where the user explicitly said "run as administrator" use `TokenElevationType`.

Comment: yeah i want the logon session for a particular program. I want to actually programatically determine the logon session of a program when it is opened by just double clicking on it and when it is opened by right clicking-->run as admin. When i used process explorer to view the logon session for both situations i got "n/a" when i ran it as admin and i want to use that information to restrict it from opening when run as admin. So would the procedure youve told me work for this or will I need Joao's method? Please let me know.

Comment: Process Explorer shows the logon session as "n/a" when it doesn't have sufficient privilege to see what the logon session is.  Looking at the logon session is not a sensible way to decide whether or not a process was launched using "run as admin".  Use the TokenElevationType option instead, this will be TokenElevationTypeFull if "run as admin" was used.

Comment: I used this code given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046097/how-to-check-if-a-process-has-the-admin-rights  --  and it works all good, I know when the user uses the run as admin and when he double clicks the app. But I guess it only works when the UAC is enabled. Will let you know for sure after some more testing. But thanks anyways for pointing me in the right direction. It helped :)

Answer (score 4):

You can call [GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the current process, then use that to call [OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to have an access token for the current process. Once you have that, you can call [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to request the [TokenSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:**

I just thought of something else you can try: Instead of the session ID, you can request the [TokenOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and once you have that, you have a security descriptor. You can then call [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the account name associated with the descriptor. Then, you can check that against "Administrator" or some such.

Comment: That retrieves the terminal services session ID, not the logon session ID.

Comment: @Joao: I need to get the logon session for a process. It is a 4 digit number with 2 characters in between, so the total length is 6. It is not the logon SID that I want to find(just added for info)

Comment: I confess I have no idea what a session ID looks like, so I don't know if what you're saying is a problem or not...

Comment: Thanks Joao for the answer. It helped me a lot.