# What techniques can detect elevation of processes

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I Know how to detect whether my own process is elevated programatically  in dotnet and Power Shell. However how does one detect the elevation of other processes in the system programatically?

for instance if you start 2 copies of calc, 1 elevated and one not. In windows 8, in task manager UI. i can go to details, and add an elevated column and see which is elevated and which is not. However I want to be able to find this out for any process, and i want to do it via code or script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1220213

Comment: That question is about the *current* process, not a *different* process. Luckily, we have [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694743/check-if-another-process-has-admin-privileges-in-net) about that, too! Note that, as I believe is explained somewhere on the linked question, you will need to have administrative privileges yourself in order to check this information on other processes. The Task Manager, of course, does.