# Administrative privilege(To check if my Outlook is opened as Administrator or not)

Tags: outlook, administrator

I have already opened Outlook i need to check it whether it is opened as administrator or not. I tried the code which is as follows but it checks if VS is opened as administrator or not.

```
    public bool IsRunningAsLocalAdmin()
    {
        WindowsIdentity cur = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        foreach (IdentityReference role in cur.Groups)
        {
            if (role.IsValidTargetType(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
            {
                SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)role.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                if (sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid) || sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid))
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I need to check whether Outlook is opened as Administrator or not.

Answer (score 0):

OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION)+[OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295(v=vs.85).aspx)(TOKEN_QUERY) to get the token, then pass that token and the SID from [CreateWellKnownSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446585(v=vs.85).aspx)(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid) to [CheckTokenMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx)()

To be able to open (almost) every process for PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access you need to be running as administrator and with [debug privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541528(VS.85).aspx).

See [Check if another process has admin privileges in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694743/check-if-another-process-has-admin-privileges-in-net) for more information.

Comment: I am new to .Net. Can you please help me out with the code??

Comment: You need to use Windows API functions.